# Apache Flink in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, faas, flink-statefun

Could anyone please let me know how I can setup Flink in my Serverless platform (FaaS) to perform event driven operations?

I looked at Flink functions and it seems to be promising. Could anyone clarify on the below?

1. What I need to install in my FaaS env. to trigger the flink function when an event (file changes in my s3 bucket) occurs?
2. I don't have big data platform and so planning to use flink in my serverless/kubernetes env.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To use StateFun You would generally need:

1. An Ingress that would trigger the functions.
2. The actual code that would react to your events (the stateful function) Dockerized
3. A way to lunch your application

Specifically:

1. Every stateful function application starts with an Ingress, basically that is a funnel of events that your functions can react to.
   In your case, you can use [Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) as your Ingress, and make sure that your S3 events will end up there.
2. The next thing that you would need, is to get yourself familiar with a stateful function SDK, either in [Java](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/sdk/java.html) or in [Python](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/sdk/python.html) and write the logic that deals with the incoming events. The result of that stage would be a [Docker image](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/deployment-and-operations/packaging.html#images).
3. Then, you need to lunch the image obtained at (2) and for that you can use Kubernetes (you don't have to).
   There are [Helm charts](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/tree/master/tools/k8s) provided for your convenience and a [simple utility](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/tree/master/statefun-examples/statefun-greeter-example/k8s) to generate the necessary k8s resources.

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. Will check Kinesis.